# Reply email not being sent in formSubmitReply

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have the following code written:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
    var userEmail = e.values[7];
    //var file = DriveApp.getFileById('SWAD_agenda_2014.pdf');
    //var userFirstName = e.values[2];
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
        //subject line text
        "Online Spotter Class Registration",
        //body of email
        "Congratulations! " + "You are ALMOST fully registered to attend the online \n" +
        "spotter class on Monday, September 22nd 2014 at 630 pm! \n\n" + 

        "Please finish your registration for the class by clicking on the following link: \n" +
        "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/register/413777265 \n\n" + 

        "Once you do, GoToMeeting will send you an email with a link to click on. \n" + 
        "When you're ready, click on that link and there will be a small download \n" + 
        "to allow you to participate through GoToMeeting. There will be time to \n" +
        "do this just before we begin, if you so choose. \n\n" +

        "Remember, if you want to actively participate, you will need a \n" +
        "microphone. It is not necessary, though. You can just listen and watch, \n" +
        "if you want.\n\n" +

        "We look forward to 'seeing' you then!\n\n" +

        "NWS Nashville",

        {name:"NWS Nashville"});
}
```

With my trigger set to submit upon receipt.  The `e.value` is 7, which is the 7th column in my spreadsheet, not counting the timestamp.

I keep getting this error email:

```
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
9/4/14 1:48 PM  formSubmitReply Invalid email: undefined (line 5, file "Code")  formSubmit  9/4/14 1:48 PM
```

This code worked before and I'm stumped why it's not working anymore.  Please help.

Comment: When you debug, does `userEmail` actually have a value?  And, is `e.value[7]` really the 7th column, or is it the 8th column?  (Off-by-one error)

Comment: Yes, I submit the form to practice, entering a valid email.  e.value[7] is actually the 8th column, but I have had it both ways (7 and 8) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: And when you step through this function in the debugger, `e.value[7]` returns a string containing an actual e-mail address, yes?  Like, `userEmail` has the expected e-mail address in it?

Comment: Nope, it's saying userEmail is undefined.  I have changed the e.value to 8 which is the 'actual' column number, vs 7 which is the value when you don't include the 'timestamp' column.  Neither work.